# CodeIgniter connect database from another hosting

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, cpanel

I have 2 hosting lets say hosting A and Hosting B.
The application using CI inside Hosting A and database too
for some reason i want upload my application to hosting B but error because database connection. how i can connect my application in hosting B but the database in hosting A. 
what should i change in my connection string ?

Answer (score 1):

For connecting to database at hosting a

1. You can directly use the ip of host a and used in codeigniter application at host b.
2. Its depend on hosting provider whether database can accept connections from other  host or not. For this contact the hosting a.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the hostname to the IP address of hosting A where your database is hosted. Also, you need to give certain permissions on Hosting A, in order for other servers to access that database.